# Scale parameter in the logit model

Tags: statistics, regression

While going thorough the logit model notes, I came across something called "scale parameter" in the likelihood. Can someone please explain what that is and what it is used for. What would happen it is not used. Also, is it used in the probit model too?

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

This was asked 5 months ago, but I'll answer it anyway.

OP, you may remember the concept of the residual sum of squares from [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). From this, we can obtain a statistic for the standard deviation of the errors in the model, by dividing the residual SS by the residual degrees of freedom. The standard deviation of the errors is also known as the *scale parameter*: it's the `sigma` in the `N(mu, sigma)` distribution for the errors in linear regression.

In logistic regression, the analogous statistic to residual SS is residual deviance: the amount of unexplained variation in the model after taking into account the effect of the predictors. Now in theory, a logistic regression doesn't have a scale parameter: notice that there is no equivalent to `sigma` in the binomial distribution. (Recall that a logistic regression assumes the data is drawn from a binomial distribution, whose parameter `p` is a function of the predictors.) However, in practice, we often observe that there is more variability in the data than can be accounted for by the model. A way of adjusting the model for this is to compute a "scale parameter" like that in linear regression: the residual deviance, divided by the residual df.

Since overdispersion is a property of the response distribution, it applies just as much for probit regression as for logistic.

It can be shown that, given certain assumptions, the residual deviance in a correctly-specified logistic/probit model should be approximately equal to the residual df: ie, the scale parameter should be about 1. A model where the scale parameter > 1 is said to be *overdispersed*; you allow for this by dividing all your t-statistics for your coefficients etc by the scale parameter, just like in linear regression.

Note that this is not always a useful rule. It depends crucially on the assumption that the number of trials per binomial observation is large, whichis often violated for real data. If you have a binary response, for example (every observation is 0 or 1), it breaks down completely.

Answer (score 1):

I find them a little tricky to understand too so bear with me, but maybe I have some insights that might be useful for you.

First of all, if you haven't already, check out Kenneth Train's book on simulation-based estimation. In his chapter on logit, there's even a sub-chapter on the scale parameter (ch. 3.3).

Basically, it differs a little bit what people are talking about so it depends on what you are thinking about. 
Some people divide the entire conditional utility of each of the choices by a lambda. This lambda will generally not be identified then because the scale of utility is unidentified (only relative differences matter). Maybe when you had probit presented, you discussed the variance of the normal error term, which is not identified.

However, there are other people that discuss them when they discuss how random utility models can be approximated by (mixed) logit models. In this sense, it is because the multinomial logit can be interpreted as a "smooth" max function. That is, if you multiply only the IID extreme value errors by a lambda, then when lambda -> 0, the logsum converges to the maximum choice (= the indirect utility). 
Kenneth Train talks about this as well, check it out.

Edit: I think actually it is mostly an important matter to ponder if you're in numerical trouble. For example, I've had some problems where most of the conditional choice probabilities for some data rows were 0 or 1 which gives problems with likelihood. Working with a higher lambda sort of "smoothed" out the probabilities (in the sense that as lambda -> infinity, all CCPs -> 1/J (where J = # of choices)).

Hope it helped.